# Solo Mayusculas y minusculas en input con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Lo que deseo es que mi funcion solo deje escribir mayusculas, minusculas y los signos # y &, intente asi, pero no me permite insertar mayusculas, solo minusculas

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#texto').on('keyup', function(){
  $(this).val(validarTexto($('#texto').val()));
});

function validarTexto(texto) {
  return texto.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z\#\&]+/g, "");
}

})
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `split()` y luego `join()`.

```js
function remplazar(elemento){
  let texto = elemento.value
  texto = texto.split(/[^A-Za-z\#\&]+/g)
  texto = texto.join("")
  elemento.value = texto
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="remplazar(this)">
```

Puede crear un objecto `RegExp` y "testear" si el entrada actual coincide con la expresión regular, si no es así eliminas la letra el ultimo carácter digitado. (ya que el carácter no valido se mostrara breve-mente quedara claro para el usuario que no es permitido)

```js
function validar(elemento){
  let texto = elemento.value
  let validar = new RegExp("[^A-Za-z\#\&]+")
  if(validar.test(texto)){
    texto = texto.substr(0,texto.length-1)
  } else{
      // accion cuando no coincide
  }
  elemento.value = texto
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="validar(this)">
```

Provee tu código eliminando `toLowerCase()` y también funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#texto').on('keyup', function(){
  $(this).val(validarTexto($('#texto').val()));
});

function validarTexto(texto) {
  return texto.replace(/[^A-Za-z\#\&]+/g, "");
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="texto">
```

Answer (score 2):

En tu función **validarTexto** usas la función **toLowerCase**, lo que cambia todas las mayúsculas a minúsculas. Simplemente no uses **.toLowerCase()**.

Answer (score 0):

solo te admite minúsculas por tu .`ToLowerCase()`, está bien usarlo para homogeneizar, pero tienes que tener cuidado con lo que haces y cómo lo usas. Ej: nombre de usuario, el usuario introduce 'usuario' y esto es equivalente a 'USUARIO', 'Usuario', etc... esto es gracias a .`ToLowerCase`(),pero en tu caso te limita lo que quieres hacer